# MS SQL Login without password

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I need to login to MS Sql from ODBC to my MS Sql instance on Linux server. Following are my question

1. Is there a way to do it without Active Directory (maybe with LDAP or ADLDS if it does not change user profile)?
2. I created a SQL Server Login without password by deselecting `enforce password policy`. I can finish adding ODBC and **Test Connection** is successful, but when I run the program it gives an error the the login has failed and in the SQL Server Log it shows:

   > Login failed for user 'gp'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided".

The program I am running is a old program and I don't have the source code to change anything in it. Currently it works with Windows Authentication on a server running Windows Server and Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: What happens if you define a password for the login gp you created and configure that password on the ODBC creation? Does the error change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [How to transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/918992/how-to-transfer-logins-and-passwords-between-instances-of-sql-server) to migrate the `gp` user from the old SQL Server instance to the new SQL Server instance.

## Analysis

The application will be logging in with the `gp` account and a pre-defined password stored in the application.

Because you have not provided a password for the new user you created on the new instance the login is failing.

## Solution

You will have to create the SQL Server login with the above mentioned method provided by Microsoft. Essentially the scripts create two procedures on the source instance in the **master** database. When you execute `EXEC sp_help_revlogin` it creates an output containing a `CREATE LOGIN ...` statement for each SQL Server Login which contains the SID and encrypted password of the original logins.

> The output script that the sp_help_revlogin stored procedure generates is the login script. This login script creates the logins that have the original Security Identifier (SID) and the original password.

You then create the required SQL Server Login on the target SQL Server Instance by running the corresponding `CREATE LOGIN....` statement for the `gp` login on the target instance.

Comment: I believe the method you described shall work only for SQL Server local logins, but the question says "Currently it works with Windows Authentication on a server running Windows Server and Microsoft SQL Server". When Windows Logins are configured, no passwords are stored on SQL Server to be retrieved and he would only need to create a login on the new instance based on the same Windows login. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are partly correct: It will work for SQL Server Logins and Windows Authenticated Logins that have been created in SQL Server. However, I deduced from his last paragraph, that he was having issues starting the application. Hence my suggestion, that the `gp` SQL Server login be transferred from the old instance to the new instance.

Comment: You are right Ronaldo, and thank you @Johnakahot2use I think what you are pointing me to interesting direction, Now I wonder the programmer created a gp account with password in the application, if so we will know. Thanks a lot will work on it and update you.

Comment: I run the script on the Source Server, on running EXEC sp_help_revlogin I got list of Login users, but non of them were user: gp. When I look into database used by program there is a gp user type created with "SQL user without login".

Comment: Are there any other database users in the source database? When you open up the tree **Databases** |  **<Source Database>** | **Security** | **Users** what do you see in there? You should see **dbo**, **guest**, **INFORMATION_SCHEMA**, **sys** and possibly the **gp** user. Any other users?

Comment: @abhay9, it is possible that on your source server the previous Windows Login used on the connection was [impersonating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#withoutLogin) the `gp` user? Please, take a look at this: [Checking impersonation in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843995/checking-impersonation-in-sql-server). If so, check these [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks).

Comment: @Ronaldo This is interesting, will see if I can impersonate Sql User to Database User

Comment: @Johnakahot2use, users underdatabase I could see gp user. But above script is for copying all the SQL user where there is no gp user.

Comment: @Johnakahot2use Sorry for delay in replying, there are other users dbo, gp, and some other users which are added because of windows authentication. Information_schema is there and there is red x mark on it. I took a full backup and restored it in Linux system and got all those users in there. I am now looking at how to use ADLDS for authentication, can you point me to any article which I can use to integrated ADLDS as authentication with sql server. I really appreciate your helping hand.